# Zsh (Wsl) can not response when cd command into the specified directory

Tags: zsh

I have the problem about zsh (wsl) in windows 11, when I cd into the specified directory, only that folder, my zsh doesn't response, and I have to ctrl+c every time I want to type the next command. I don't know what this problem is, and how to fix this. My PowerShell still works normally, only zsh encounters this error. Anyone can help me pls?

I try waiting some minutes and this evently responses, this folder is my repo git in windows, i use zsh to cd into this, and it takes me quite lots of time to enter this folder. How to fix this problem?

Comment: With this exotic case, I think a screenshot would help. Make sure that you do a `echo $ZSH_VERSION` before doing the `cd`, so that we can see what zsh you are running.

Comment: I found the same problem in some other webs, and the answer for this, zsh is very slow when i try to do something in the very large git repo. I wonder that whether there is any way to solve or improve the speed of zsh in this case?

Comment: My guess is that it is not so much the problem of the shell itself, but of the operating system and of the way the shell is configured. You now mentione _git_ in your comment, for instance: If you configure the shell prompt in a way that it displays information abuot the repo, it can really take long on some platforms, In this case, you would have to time the different parts of the prompt differently. With that little information you are posting here, one can't give any good recommendation.

Comment: I found how to fix this, in .zshrc config file, i change disable_untracked_files_dirty into true. It'll speed up when i want to cd into the large repo git. Anyway, thank you so much

Comment: For the benefit of others, you may want to elaborate your solution in an answer (you **can** answer your own questions). Make sure that you write it in a way so that the answer will be of general use.

Answer (score 0):

I found out in many webs to look for any solution to fix or improve this problem, and i evently also found 2 ways for this.
First, change the line "disable_untracked_files_dirty" into true in your .zshrc file.
Second, if you're using powerlevel10k, add this line "typeset -g POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet" into the .p10k.zsh file if you're using this file to config your powerlevel10k, or add this line "POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT=quiet" into your .zshrc file if you're using .zshrc to config your powerlevel10k.
Hope to help

Comment: This explanation needs some improvement. After all, `disable_untracked_files_dirty` is no variable with special meaning to zsh, and it is unclear, how this realtes to your problem. You would need to explain at least how you had set up your .zshrc so that this variable is relevant. The same is true about `POWERLEVEL9K_INSTANT_PROMPT`, in particular since your original question does not mention that you are using _powerlevel10k_, whatever that is.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).